# Use Web NFC on Android Webview?

Tags: java, android-studio, webview, kiosk, webnfc

I made a React web app that reads the uid from RFID cards of my customers. This works fine with the Web NFC api on Goolge Chrome. To display the app in fullscreen mode on a tablet with NFC interface I created a simple Java App to output the web app with Webview.

The site is loading fine but Webview is not asking the user for NFC permission and I get this error message:

**"NFC permission request denied."**

I tried a few kiosk browser apps but they are also working with Webview and can't handle the Web NFC requests.

Is there any solution? Thank you!

Here an example:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.shop;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-nfc/");
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }
    public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shop">
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.shop">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Web NFC is sadly not supported in Android WebView.

Source: https://chromestatus.com/feature/6261030015467520

Quick question: Why not using the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) instead?

```js
document.body.requestFullscreen();
```